# Override keydownevent in NSTextfield

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I made a subclass of the nstextfield and i override the keydown event but my code doesn't work, then i override de keyup event and the code works perfectly.
My keydown code(doesn't work):

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Key released: %hi", [event keyCode]);

    if ([event keyCode]==125){

        [[self window] selectKeyViewFollowingView:self];
    }
    if ([event keyCode]==126){

        [[self window] selectKeyViewPrecedingView:self];
    }

}
```

My keyup code (it works):

```
-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent*)event
{if ([event keyCode]==125){

        [[self window] selectKeyViewFollowingView:self];
    }
    if ([event keyCode]==126){

        [[self window] selectKeyViewPrecedingView:self];
    }

    if ([event keyCode]==36){

        [[self window] selectKeyViewFollowingView:self];
    }

    }
```

I don't see where is the problem with my keydown code. Any suggest will be accepted

EDIT:
I have read that you have to subclass NSTextView instead of NSTextField.

Comment: Please provide details describing "doesn't work".

Comment: does it perform the NSLog? is it being called at all? are these the same exact instance of the same exact class where one works and one doesn't?

Comment: You're mixing up terms here.  You're not "overriding" the event, you're just listening for it.  If you were overriding it, you would make it do something other than what it was intended to do.

Comment: ok but that doesn't help me at all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The keydown event can't be overriden in a NSTextField, if you want , you could override the keydown event of the super view or you could use a NSTextView or just override the keyup event in the NSTextField

Answer (score 14):

You can do it without subclassing by using NSTextFieldDelegate methods:

As @Darren Inksetter said, you can use [`control:textView:doCommandBySelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSControlTextEditingDelegate/control:textView:doCommandBySelector:)

First, declare NSTextFieldDelegate in your interface tag.
Then implement the method:

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
{
    if( commandSelector == @selector(moveUp:) ){
        // Do yourthing here, like selectKeyViewFollowingView
        return YES;    // Return YES means don't pass it along responders chain. Return NO if you still want system's action on this key.
    }
    if( commandSelector == @selector(moveDown:) ){
        // Do the same with the keys you want to track
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This protocol function apparently does not exist anymore. (macOS 10.13)

Comment: @gerbil It still exists in a different protocol: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontroltexteditingdelegate/1428898-control?language=objc

Answer (score 6):

Swift 5 example.

```swift
    func control(_ control: NSControl, textView: NSTextView, doCommandBy commandSelector: Selector) -> Bool {
        switch commandSelector {
        case #selector(moveUp(_:)):
            impl.tableView.doCommand(by: commandSelector)
            return true
        case #selector(moveDown(_:)):
            impl.tableView.doCommand(by: commandSelector)
            return true
        default: return false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You will want to look at

```
control:textView:doCommandBySelector:
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html